# Keeping only the "Necessary and Sufficient features" in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that is composed of 2 columns as follows (as an example):

```
COLUMN-1 COLUMN-2
feature1 feature5
feature2 feature6
feature3 feature7
feature4 feature8
```

In this dataframe, features on the same row are related to each other. (Eg. feature 1 and 5)
So using either one, I can calculate the other.

In this dataframe, I need to keep a minimum number of features to compute the all features.
Thus, I need to find the critical features.

**Example-1**:

```
INPUT:

COLUMN-1 COLUMN-2
feature1 feature4
feature2 feature5
feature3 feature6

DESIRED OUTPUT:
feature1
feature2
feature3
```

Above I can calculate features 4,5,6.

**Example-2**:

```
INPUT:

COLUMN-1 COLUMN-2
feature1 feature3
feature1 feature4
feature2 feature6
feature3 feature6

DESIRED OUTPUT:
feature1
```

First, feature3 can be calculated by using feature1.
Later, feature6 can be calculated by using feature3.
Later, feature2 can be calculated by using feature6.
Later, feature4 can be calculated by using feature1.

My dataframe can hold thousands of rows.
So I need an elegant solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think of your features as nodes and your data as an edgelist in a graph. You need one row per connected subgraph. The `igraph` package can help. (Might be complicated, it might need to be a directed graph, but still the `igraph` package can help.)

Comment: You basically need to keep only the distinct values from the first column?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro no! Not first column. Please see example-2.

Comment: I guess the desired output in the second example should be any one of the elements from the two columns, e.g., `feature1` only.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding you're right sir!

Comment: See my attempt below. Hope that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution via using `igraph` package

```
memb <- clusters(graph_from_data_frame(df,directed = FALSE))$membership
res <- names(memb)[!duplicated(memb)]
```

---

**Example**

- Given `df <- df1`, we will get

```
> res
[1] "feature1" "feature2" "feature3"
```

- Given `df <- df2`, we will get

```
> res
[1] "feature1"
```

---

**Data**

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(`COLUMN-1` = c("feature1", "feature2", "feature3"
), `COLUMN-2` = c("feature4", "feature5", "feature6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(`COLUMN-1` = c("feature1", "feature1", "feature2", 
"feature3"), `COLUMN-2` = c("feature3", "feature4", "feature6",
"feature6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```